# Ansible remove item from list

Tags: ansible

based on a variable I need two versions of the "same" list and I would like to avoid to duplicate the code as follows:

```
- set_fact: 
     type1: false    (or true!)

- set_fact:
    mylist: 
    - "show command1"
    - "show command2.1"
    - "show command3"
    - "show command4"
  when: type1

- set_fact:
    mylist: 
    - "show command1"
    - "show command2.1"
    - "show command2.2"
    - "show command3"
    - "show command4"
  when: not type1
```

Is there a way (Jinja?) to avoid duplicates?

Riccardo Russo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is:

### mytemplate.j2

```
mycmd:
- "show command1"
- "show command2.1"
{% if not type1 %}
- "show command2.2"
{% endif %}
- "show command3"
- "show command4"
```

### plb.yaml

```
- set_fact:
    myvar: "{{ lookup('template', './mytemplate.j2') | from_yaml }}" 

- debug:
    var: myvar["cmd"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [merge lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) in ansible:

```
- set_fact:
    mylist:
    - "show command1"
    - "show command2.1"
    - "show command3"
    - "show command4"

- set_fact:
    mylist: '{{ mylist | union([ "show command2.2" ]) }}'
  when: not type1
```

If order matters you can sort your list.

```
mylist: '{{ mylist | union([ "show command2.2" ]) | sort }}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but order is important and "sort" is clearly not applicable to mantain it

Comment: If you don't know the position before, where to put the new item in the list, then you must have a second parameter, the position, to merge the two lists. First you have to split at the merging position in two parts, then append to the first list and merge again.